# How to do Dynamic php Namespacing

Tags: php, dynamic, namespaces

OK, Here is the actual issue broken down:

using namespacing:

```
 \home\Homecontroller::get(); // returns what I want
```

Without using namespacing:

```
$str = "Homecontroller@get"
$caller = explode('@', $str);
$caller[0]::$caller[1](); // returns what I want
```

Every attempt to do this dynamically fails

```
\$namespace\$caller[0]::$caller[1](); // fails
eval("\\${namespace}\\${caller[0]}::${caller[1]}()"); // fails
```

in the homecontroller.php file I have:

```
<?php
namespace home;
class Homecontroller {
    public function Homecontroller()
    {
        throw new Exception("Homecontroller is a static class");
    }
    public static function jsonify($data)
    {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2016 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        print json_encode ($data);
        exit();
    }
    public static function get()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['message'] = "You have called the GET function";
        self::jsonify($data);
    }
}
```

I am building a framework that needs to respect the namespacing, but not specifically aware of them. I need to keep the namespaces listed in an external config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the fully qualified class name as a string, then call the method on it:

```
namespace home;
class Homecontroller {
    private function __construct()
    {}
    public static function jsonify($data)
    {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2016 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        print json_encode ($data);
        exit();
    }
    public static function get()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['message'] = "You have called the GET function";
        self::jsonify($data);
    }
}
$namespace = "home";
$str = "Homecontroller@get";
$caller = explode('@', $str);
$cls = "\\$namespace\\$caller[0]";
$method = $caller[1];

$cls::$method();
//or use call_user_func
call_user_func([$cls, $method]);
```

Comment: That is actually amazing. Both of those options solved the issue, and helped me understand namespacing a little better.

Comment: No problem. Note i also cleaned up the constructor - php no longer user `function {ClassName}(){}` as a constructor, you should use `__construct()` instead. Also, by making its access modifier `private` it is not possible to create an instance of the class, so the exception in not required

Comment: I appreciate that. I have been away from php for a few years, and there has been a few changes I was not aware of.